# Detect web-browser or mobile to display links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobile

I am writing a rails application and need to present different links for mobile users to normal web browser users. For example, if the user is on a mobile I want to display:

```
<a href="instagram://user?username=<%= photo.author %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-block"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> Captured by <%= photo.author %></a>
```

If the user is on a browser I want to display:

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/<%= photo.author %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-block"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> Captured by <%= photo.author %></a>
```

What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Browser data comes in the form of the [`user_agent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) object:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   helper_method :mobile?

   private

   def mobile? # has to be in here because it has access to "request"
      request.user_agent =~ /\b(Android|iPhone|iPad|Windows Phone|Opera Mobi|Kindle|BackBerry|PlayBook)\b/i
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following in your views:

```
#app/views/controller/view.html.erb
<% if mobile? %>
   ... do something for mobile
<% else %>
   ... do something else
<% end %>
```

Being honest, I don't get why people hard-code their mobile interface work. If you use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) properly, you shouldn't have an issue with the files, although your case certainly appears to require the server-side conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to achieve [deep linking](http://mobiledeeplinking.org/). For that I would suggest you to use [deeplink.me](https://deeplink.me/). However if you want to do it the rails way, then there is a gem named [`browser`](https://github.com/fnando/browser). Following code will help you set it up.

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'browser'
```

then in your

**application_controller.rb:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_browser

  def get_browser
    @browser = Browser.new(:ua => request.user_agent)
  end   
end
```

and finally in your views, you can do:

```
<% if @browser.mobile? %>
   <a href="instagram://user?username=<%= photo.author %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-block"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> Captured by <%= photo.author %></a>
<% else %>
  <a href="http://instagram.com/<%= photo.author %>" target="_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-block"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i> Captured by <%= photo.author %></a>
<% end %>
```

Comment: awesome, going to give this a try!

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you use a front-end work like Bootstrap or Foundation. Those frameworks allow you to orient to both mobile views and desktop views.

Comment: I am using bootstrap, but I still need to determine if its a mobile device to display a different link...more details needed for this answer I think :)